# Generate 1 MB (or n MB) text file in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, text-files, dynamically-generated

I need to create a text file (alphanumeric) with size (exact or nearly) in MB equal to my input number, such as 1 MB. I tried to generated a string, with think that one char is 16 bit or 2 byte, so:
1KB = 1024 Bytes = 1024 x 8 Bits = 1024 x 8 / 16 chars = 512 chars.
But the generated file is not very seem to be right :(
If I generate byte array and write it to file, the size is pretty correct!

```
 public static void generateDummyFileBySize(long sizeInMb, string filePath) {

            byte[] data = new byte[sizeInMb * 1024 * 1024];
            Random rng = new Random();
            rng.NextBytes(data);
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);
        }
```

Help me please. This is the code I used to generated text file

```
public static String generateStringSize(long sizeByte)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Random rd = new Random();
            /**
             * Byte -> Bit -> Divide by 16 to num of char
             * */
            var numOfChars = sizeByte * 8 ;
            string allows = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            int maxIndex = allows.Length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfChars; i++)
            {
                int index = rd.Next(maxIndex);
                char c = allows[index];
                sb.Append(c);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

public static void generateTextFileBySize(long size, string fileName)
        {
            long sizeOld = size;
            try
            {

                String s;
                String path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                var physicPath = path + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + fileName;
                File.Delete(physicPath);
                if (size <= MAX_SIZE)
                {
                    s = StringUtil.generateStringSize(size);
                    Console.WriteLine("Generated a string with length " + size);
                    File.WriteAllText(physicPath, s, Encoding.UTF8);
                }
                else
                {
                    while (size > MAX_SIZE)
                    {
                        s = StringUtil.generateStringSize(MAX_SIZE);
                        Console.WriteLine("Appending " + MAX_SIZE + " to file");
                        File.AppendAllText(physicPath, s, Encoding.UTF8);
                        size -= MAX_SIZE;
                    }
                    s = StringUtil.generateStringSize(size);
                    File.AppendAllText(physicPath, s, Encoding.UTF8);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Created file named " + fileName + " with size " + sizeOld + " bytes.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error when generating file");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where are you writing the characters to File, as in case of Byte[] ? There's always a difference in the in memory and on disk size.

Comment: Sorry :) I added the code and updated the question. In the fact, my size never pass MAX_SIZE, to you can ignore that case

Comment: Every character in the `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789` occupies 1 byte when encoded in utf8.

Comment: 1 issue is you're writing it in UTF8, which is a variably sized encoding. Since you're only using ASCII characters, each character will use 1 byte.

Comment: I just tested, on removing the `*8` and supplying the value `1024*1024`, you will be able to get precise 1 MB file on using the Encoding ASCII

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
var numOfChars = sizeByte * 8 ;
```

You create eight times the characters you need. Instead just use

```
var numOfChars = sizeByte;
```

Each of the characters you use occupies one byte when stored as UTF-8, so you don't need to use a different number of characters than the number of bytes you want.

Answer (score 2):

Made following changes to your code:

Removed `8` from `var numOfChars = sizeByte*8;`, since in `ASCII encoding`, each `character` is `1 byte` also changed the Encoding to `ASCII instead of UTF8` to be precise for characters.

Following is the working code, generates precise 1 MB file, I have tested for other values like 8 MB, 7 MB, result is accurate

```
    String s = generateStringSize(1024 * 1024); 
    File.WriteAllText("D:\\Test1.txt", s, Encoding.ASCII);
```